# Alarm Repeats Infinitely -- Locking up phone

Tags: android, crash, alarmmanager, infinite-loop

The alarm date and time and created separately and then set one alarm as:

```
public void schedule(Context context) {
    setAlarmActive(true);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);

    // Adding random signature
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Previously setting the time
    //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    // Testing adding the alarm date to this
    Calendar alarmSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Setting the time:
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.HOUR, getAlarmTime().get(Calendar.HOUR));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getAlarmTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // Setting the date:
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.MONTH, alarmDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmSchedule.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

The alarm does goes off at the correct date and time, but when it does, it repeats the alert dialog infinity, like an infinite loop, locking up the phone until the user must restart the device and delete the alarm.

How can I alleviate this issue?

Setting the date:

```
  public void setAlarmDate(Calendar alarmDate) {
        this.alarmDate = alarmDate;
    }

    public void setAlarmDate(String alarmDate) {

        String[] datePieces = alarmDate.split("-");
        Log.v("setAlarmDate-Year", datePieces[0]);
        Log.v("setAlarmDate-Month", datePieces[1]);
        Log.v("setAlarmDate-Day", datePieces[2]);

        Calendar newAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Taking from above, adding now a specific date
        newAlarmDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,
                Integer.parseInt(datePieces[0]));
        newAlarmDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,
                Integer.parseInt(datePieces[1]) - 1); 
        newAlarmDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                Integer.parseInt(datePieces[2]));
        setAlarmDate(newAlarmDate);

    }
```

Setting the time:
    public void setAlarmTime(Calendar alarmTime) {
        this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
    }

```
public void setAlarmTime(String alarmTime) {

    String[] timePieces = alarmTime.split(":");

    Calendar newAlarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
            Integer.parseInt(timePieces[0]));
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(timePieces[1]));
    newAlarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    setAlarmTime(newAlarmTime);
}
```

The broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent mathAlarmServiceIntent = new Intent(
                context,
                AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever.class);
        context.sendBroadcast(mathAlarmServiceIntent, null);

        StaticWakeLock.lockOn(context);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        final Alarm alarm = (Alarm) bundle.getSerializable("alarm");

        Intent mathAlarmAlertActivityIntent;

        mathAlarmAlertActivityIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmAlertActivity.class);

        // Should create a notification that event is occurring
        mathAlarmAlertActivityIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);

        mathAlarmAlertActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(mathAlarmAlertActivityIntent);
    }

}
```

The AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever class:

```
public class AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever", "onReceive()");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }

}
```

AlarmService class:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"onCreate()");
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    private Alarm getNext(){
        Set<Alarm> alarmQueue = new TreeSet<Alarm>(new Comparator<Alarm>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Alarm lhs, Alarm rhs) {
                int result = 0;
                long diff = lhs.getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis() - rhs.getAlarmTime().getTimeInMillis();                
                if(diff>0){
                    return 1;
                }else if (diff < 0){
                    return -1;
                }
                return result;
            }
        });

        Database.init(getApplicationContext());
        List<Alarm> alarms = Database.getAll();

        for(Alarm alarm : alarms){
            if(alarm.getAlarmActive())
                alarmQueue.add(alarm);
        }
        if(alarmQueue.iterator().hasNext()){
            return alarmQueue.iterator().next();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Service#onDestroy()
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Database.deactivate();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"onStartCommand()");
        Alarm alarm = getNext();
        if(null != alarm){
            alarm.schedule(getApplicationContext());
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),alarm.getTimeUntilNextAlarmMessage());

        }else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("alarm", new Alarm());

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);           
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

}
```

AlarmAlertActivity:

```
public class AlarmAlertActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Alarm alarm;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private StringBuilder answerBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //private MathProblem mathProblem;
    private Vibrator vibrator;

    private boolean alarmActive;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private TextView problemView;
    private TextView answerView;
    private String answerString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_alert);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        alarm = (Alarm) bundle.getSerializable("alarm");


        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.openEvent)).setOnClickListener(this);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Incoming call: "
                            + incomingNumber);
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Call State Idle");
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    }
                    break;
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };

        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        // Toast.makeText(this, answerString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startAlarm();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        alarmActive = true;
    }

    private void startAlarm() {

        if (alarm.getAlarmTonePath() != "") {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            if (alarm.getVibrate()) {
                vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                long[] pattern = { 1000, 200, 200, 200 };
                vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,
                        Uri.parse(alarm.getAlarmTonePath()));
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                alarmActive = false;
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!alarmActive)
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        StaticWakeLock.lockOff(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            if (vibrator != null)
                vibrator.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String button = (String) v.getTag();
        if (!alarmActive)
            return;

        // When click the view, shut off the alarm
        alarmActive = false;
        if (vibrator != null)
            vibrator.cancel();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {

        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // and show the details:
        Intent getEvent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
        startActivity(getEvent);



        this.finish();

//      v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
//      if (button.equalsIgnoreCase("clear")) {
//          if (answerBuilder.length() > 0) {
//              answerBuilder.setLength(answerBuilder.length() - 1);
//              answerView.setText(answerBuilder.toString());
//          }
//      } else if (button.equalsIgnoreCase(".")) {
//          if (!answerBuilder.toString().contains(button)) {
//              if (answerBuilder.length() == 0)
//                  answerBuilder.append(0);
//              answerBuilder.append(button);
//              answerView.setText(answerBuilder.toString());
//          }
//      } else if (button.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
//          if (answerBuilder.length() == 0) {
//              answerBuilder.append(button);
//              answerView.setText(answerBuilder.toString());
//          }
//      } else {
//          answerBuilder.append(button);
//          answerView.setText(answerBuilder.toString());
//          // If click the button, then open feast app with the special event details
//          if (isAnswerCorrect()) {
//              alarmActive = false;
//              if (vibrator != null)
//                  vibrator.cancel();
//              try {
//                  mediaPlayer.stop();
//              } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
//
//              }
//              try {
//                  mediaPlayer.release();
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//
//              }
//              this.finish();
//              // OPEN FEASTAPP event with those event details
//          }
//      }
//      if (answerView.getText().length() >= answerString.length()
//              && !isAnswerCorrect()) {
//          answerView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//      } else {
//          answerView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
//      }
//      }
    }

    public boolean isAnswerCorrect() {
        //boolean correct = false;
        /*
        try {
            correct = mathProblem.getAnswer() == Float.parseFloat(answerBuilder
                    .toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        */
        // So once click, it will be correct and close out the app
        boolean correct = true;
        return correct;
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d("TAG", "Notification sent successfully.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which alert dialog is repeated infinitely? Is it your alert dialog? Perhaps the problem is your code in AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever?

Comment: @Karakuri, I have updated the code. Is there a way to view a list of all alarms created?

Comment: There is no way to see which alarms are scheduled, `AlarmManager` doesn't provide that. So far I still don't see any code that produces an alert dialog, and my impression is the problem might be in that code.

Comment: @Karakuri I added the alert activity

Comment: @Karakuri In the alarm alert activity, in onClick I added:  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("alarm", Alarm.class);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

In the alarm alert activity, in onClick I added:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("alarm", Alarm.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

To cancel the alarm